# Relationship between tables and hasManyThrough

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I got 3 models in Laravel (User, Payment, Purchase).

What I want is pretty simple but i've no idea how to do it with Laravel/Eloquent ; I would succeed with raw SQL.

I want to get the purchases of a user without much code.

The `users` table is linked with the `payments` table which is linked to the `purchases` table. The finale code would look like

```
$purchases = $user->purchases()->get();
```

My models look like this

[image: purchases and payments models]

So I tried a simple

```
public function purchases()
{

    return $this->hasManyThrough('Purchase', 'Payment');

}
```

But it doesn't work

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'purchases.payment_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `purchases`.*,
>   `payments`.`user_id` from `purchases` inner join `payments` on
>   `payments`.`id` = `purchases`.`payment_id` where `payments`.`user_id`
>   = 1)

Pretty simple here, it searches `purchases`.`payment_id` but my table organization needs a join with `payment`.`purchase_id`. How can you tell that to Laravel ? Is there another way to do what I want ?

Maybe I could do it in raw SQL but keep the object generated via Eloquent ? I'm open to any solution ^^

Detail : I cannot rewrite my tables.

Comment: how is your model related, give the database schema

Comment: Should 'purchases.payment_id' be 'purchases.id' ?

Comment: It's not `hasManyThrough`. It's `belongsToMany`. Not sure if you really want the purchases to be linked via payments, but maybe that's OK in your use-case.